# Print usps Shipping Label

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, api

I already did a code for print label that is working fine on usps server . I just need to print pdf. How can I do this?

```
 private void BindDetail()
    {
        //to test the upsp used below code
        USPSManager m = new USPSManager("USERID", false);
        Package p = new Package();
        p.FromAddress.Contact = "John Smith";
        p.FromAddress.Address2 = "475 L'Enfant Plaza, SW";
        p.FromAddress.City = "Washington";
        p.FromAddress.State = "DC";
        p.FromAddress.Zip = "20260";
        p.FromAddress.ZipPlus4 = "2060";
        p.ToAddress.Contact = "Tom Customer";
        p.ToAddress.Address1 = "STE 201";
        p.ToAddress.Address2 = "6060 PRIMACY PKWY";
        p.ToAddress.City = "Memphis";
        p.ToAddress.State = "TN";
        p.ToAddress.Zip = "20219";
        p.ToAddress.ZipPlus4 = "2022";
        p.WeightInOunces = 2;
        p.ServiceType = ServiceType.Priority;
        p.SeparateReceiptPage = false;
        p.LabelImageType = LabelImageType.PDF;
        p.PackageSize = PackageSize.Regular;
        p.PackageType = PackageType.Flat_Rate_Box;
        //  p.ShippingLabel=
        p = m.GetDeliveryConfirmationLabel(p);
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned that you already did the code and you are getting the response form server ; then in Order to print the label you just need to convert GetDeliveryConfirmationLabel to an image, you'll have a file called delivery_confirm.tif you can print that into an image. You can use the following from base64String to image

```
 public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
 {
  // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
  byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,imageBytes.Length);
    // Convert byte[] to Image
    ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
    return image;
  }
```